# R script for Leasts Square Monte Carlo. How to explain vol and mean?

Tags: option-pricing, programming, monte-carlo, american-options

I am trying to do a Least Squares Monte Carlo in `R`. I don't know if it is the right place to post this, but I am out of options. I don't understand the following lines of the script.

```
mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[1:n]))/(K+1)
vol = (k*dt/(K+1))^0.5*z`
```

Why is `(K+1)` used? Is it supposed to be `k` instand of `K`?

The full script is the following:

```
  lsm = function(n = 50000, d = 50, S0 = 38, K = 40, sigma = 0.2
               , r = 0.06, T = 1)
{
  # S0 = initial asset price
  # K = strike price
  # r = risk-free interest rate
  # sigma = volatility
  # T = maturity time
  # n = Number of paths simulated
  # d = Number of time steps in the simulation
  s0 = S0/K
  dt = T/d
  z = rnorm(n)
  s.t = s0*exp((r - 0.5*sigma^2)*T + sigma*z*(T^0.5))
  s.t[(n+1):(2*n)] = s0*exp((r - 0.5*sigma^2)*T - sigma*z*(T^0.5))
  CC = pmax(1-s.t, 0)
  payoffeu = exp(-r*T)*(CC[1:n]+CC[(n+1):(2*n)])/2*K
  euprice = mean(payoffeu)

  for(k in (d-1):1)
  {
    z = rnorm(n)
    mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[1:n]))/(K+1)
    vol = (k*dt/(K+1))^0.5*z
    s.t.1 = exp(mean+sigma*vol)
    mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[(n+1):(2*n)]))/(k+1)
    s.t.1[(n+1):(2*n)] = exp(mean-sigma*vol)
    CE = pmax(1-s.t.1, 0)
    idx = (1:(2*n))[CE > 0]
    discountedCC = CC[idx]*exp(-r*dt)
    basis1 = s.t.1[idx] 
    basis2 = (s.t.1[idx])^2 
    p = lm(discountedCC ~ basis1 + basis2)$coefficients
    estimatedCC = p[1] + p[2]*basis1 + p[3]*basis2
    EF = rep(0, 2*n)
    EF[idx] = (CE[idx] > estimatedCC)
    CC = (EF == 0)* CC * exp(-r*dt) + (EF == 1)*CE
    s.t = s.t.1
  }

  payoff = exp(-r*dt)*(CC[1:n]+CC[(n+1):(2*n)])/2
  usprice = mean(payoff*K)
  error = 1.96*sd(payoff*K)/sqrt(n)
  earlyex = usprice - euprice
  data.frame(usprice, error, euprice)
}

lsm()
```

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the author of the R script. His answer was that the "K"s in

`mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[1:n]))/(K+1)
 vol = (k*dt/(K+1))^0.5*z
 s.t.1 = exp(mean+sigma*vol)
 mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[(n+1):(2*n)]))/(k+1)`

should all the "k"s. It makes more sense.

Corrected:

`mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[1:n]))/(k+1)
 vol = (k*dt/(k+1))^0.5*z
 s.t.1 = exp(mean+sigma*vol)
 mean = (log(s0)+k*log(s.t[(n+1):(2*n)]))/(k+1)`

Comment: ROFL. So the published code is wrong. Did Shariq Mohammed get an A in the course?